# The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; However my path is correct

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

[image]java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; However my path is correct.

```
if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome") && OS == "Mac") {

        System.out.println("==============================================" );
        System.out.println("OS Detected : MAC , Browser Launched : Chrome" );
        System.out.println("==============================================" );

        System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver", "./lib/chromedriver");

        Boolean headlesschrome = false;

        if (headlesschrome==true) {

            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1200,800");
            dvr = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
            //dvr.manage().window().fullscreen();

        }else if (headlesschrome==false)

        {
            dvr = new ChromeDriver();
            dvr.manage().window().fullscreen();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`W`** letter in this line:

```
System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver", "./lib/chromedriver");
```

It's should:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./lib/chromedriver");
```

Make sure it's not uppercase

Comment: can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77721783/how-to-use-chrome-driver-115-above-on-mac-with-existing-code-base-initialize and help ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your chrome driver version , you should use right chrome driver version according chrome browser version 
https://chromedriver.chromium.org you can download version of chrome driver from this site

Comment: can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77721783/how-to-use-chrome-driver-115-above-on-mac-with-existing-code-base-initialize and clarify