# How to use Chrome driver 115 & above on Mac with existing code base ( initialize & launch headless browser )?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation, webautomation

I was using old version of chrome and chrome driver ( < 115 ) for testing purpose on Mac.

I was having below code which has stopped working

```
private static ChromeOptions options;

        options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors","--disable-extensions","--no-sandbox","--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

STEPS

1. Went to https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
2. Downloaded mac-x64
3. Unzipped file and moved "Google Chrome for Testing" to Applications

What changes do I need to do to get earlier code working ?